# Efficiently Create HDF5 Image Dataset for Neural Network Training with Memory Limitations

Tags: python, image, pytorch, hdf5, h5py

I am having big image datasets to train CNN's on. Since I cannot load all the images into my RAM I plan to dump them into a HDF5 file (with h5py) and then iterate over the set batchwise, as suggested in

[Most efficient way to use a large data set for PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576113/most-efficient-way-to-use-a-large-data-set-for-pytorch)

I tried creating an own dataset for every picture, located in the same group, which is very fast. But I could not figure out to iterate over all datasets in the group, except for accessing the set by its name.
As an alternative I tried putting all the images itereatively into one dataset by extending its shape, according to

[How to append data to one specific dataset in a hdf5 file with h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072859/how-to-append-data-to-one-specific-dataset-in-a-hdf5-file-with-h5py)
and

[incremental writes to hdf5 with h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655588/incremental-writes-to-hdf5-with-h5py)

but this is very slow. Is there a faster way to create a HDF5 dataset to iterate over?

Comment: You can iterate over all datasets in a group by using group.keys() and checking for instances of h5py.Dataset. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34330283/how-to-differentiate-between-hdf5-datasets-and-groups-with-h5py

Comment: The problem with this is I would like to access the data batchwise, e.g. 32 images at a time. Creating this batch from single group datasets in every epoch again is very slow...

Comment: You shouldn't have each image as its own dataset, but rather a large dataset whose first axis represent images. So a stack of 10 256x256 RGB images should be a dataset with shape [10, 256, 256, 3]

Comment: Thank you! I realized the dataset creation can be sped up a lot by not compressing the data and not reshaping the dataset every iteration.

Comment: The most important things are chunk_shape and chunk_cache. The documentation isn't very good on this topics. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405220/4045774 Quite common errors are also opening/closing the hdf5-file on every iteration. If you do it the right way, you should easily reach the sequential IO-speed of a HDD or SATA-SSD. But without a code sample it is hard to say why your implementation is so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I found a very helpful resource on this subject that I wanted to share:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-and-hdf5/9781491944981/ch04.html

Basically, the hdf5 (with chunks enabled) is like a little filesystem. It stores data in chunks scattered throughout memory. So like a filesystem, it benefits from locality. If the chunks are the same shape as the array sections you're trying to access, reading/writing will be fast. If the data you're looking for is scattered across multiple chunks, access will be slow.

So in the case of training a NN on images, you're probably going to have to make the images a standard size. Set `chunks=(1,) + image_shape`, or even better, `chunks=(batch_size,) + image_shape` when creating the dataset, and reading/writing will be a lot faster.